# Laravel 5 DOMPDF - Stream Only

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I want just to stream pdf file in the browser. I have folder `invoice` inside `public` folder. Inside `invoice` folder I have my file. I want to stream that file in browser via `dompdf` laravel package.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

I have tried something like

> return \PDF::loadFile(public_path().'/invoice/'.$invoice_name)->stream($invoice_name);

but it doesn't work.

Here is the response:

> %PDF-1.3 1 0 obj > endobj 2 0 obj > endobj 3 0 obj > >> /MediaBox
>   [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890] >> endobj 4 0 obj [/PDF /Text ] endobj 5
>   0 obj > endobj 6 0 obj > endobj 7 0 obj > stream xWMs0WPoY=B?
>   MM?N.~=?Vr$;}?_#J(>9I(`tFl`78Va~W_G8fI&01M:s.N.]?ygy{*t7yUE,M},jx Or"$
>   fG ?1DQ%BCWlJJ] ?A[?3feh|"3bmyEB&R5?E?EDhuWtM+**iVy[e(+[\b m?``iIenq2m
>   |nV?;%?N1q?lw*4c
>   +..jX$??VL3>pjxs`4)d*uER9(N~_{6

I really have no idea what to do. :)

**$invoice_name** is name of pdf file i.g "invoice-22.pdf"

Comment: it shows me some crazy data, not the file that I want to.

Comment: i suggest to edit your post and specify the data (or part of it) that you get as error, so it would be possible to understand what cloud be wrong

Comment: That is the actual PDF document, you're just seeing the source instead of being rendered as a PDF. For some reason the content type (which is set by dompdf before streaming the content) is being overridden. Could there be some kind of post-processing going on after you return the call to the `stream()` method?

Comment: There is no post-processing.

Comment: Should I set Content-Type manually?